# MongoDB find user by search returning all users

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am trying to query a user by their name field, and I am testing it in insomnia. I have my user schema like so:

```
const userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  id: { type: String },

  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  companion: {
    type: String,
    required: false
  },
  bio: { 
    type: String,
    required: false
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    min: 5
  },
  userImage: {
    type: String,
    required: false,
  },
});
```

And I have my route for /search which runs the getUserBySearch function:
`router.get('/search', getUserBySearch)`

`getUserBySearch` logic:

```
export const getUserBySearch = async (req, res) => {
                         // tried req.query and req.query.search
  const { searchQuery } = req.params
  try {
              // make the search query not case sensitive
    const user = new RegExp(searchQuery, `i`)

    //find the user's name using the name field
    const userFound = await User.find({name: user})
    res.json({data: userFound})

  } catch (error) {
    res.status(404).json({message: error.message})
  }
}
```

Tested in insomnia under the route: `http://localhost:3001/user/search?searchQuery=test`

I should only be receiving the users whose `name` field include `test`; however I get back 200 response with **ALL** of the users in the DB. how can I only retrieve the users related to my search query?

Comment: Hmm... Does this work to just set the `name` to a `RegExp`?  I'm a bit surprised.  I would have expected a query filter needs to explicitly be formed as a regex query like `{ name: { $regex: /^ABC/i } }`.  I mean, it's not impossible that Mongoose might have a feature to do this automatically for you, but maybe not.  I'm not personally familiar enough with it to answer, but it seems suspicious.  All the [MongoDB examples](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/) I've seen explicitly spell out `$regex` in the query (filter document).

Answer (score 0):

In your case `http://localhost:3001/user/search?searchQuery=test`,
you should be accessing the `?searchQuery=test` as `req.query.searchQuery`:

```js
const { searchQuery } = req.query;
const user = new RegExp(searchQuery, `i`);
```

Since, you were wrongly reading the query value, you had `undefined` as a value for `user` constant, hence getting all users in the DB.

Comment: so youre saying it should be const { searchQuery } = req.query.searchQuery ....

Comment: `const { searchQuery } = req.query`

Answer (score 0):

```
exports.searchRecipe = async(req,res) => {
  try {
    let searchTerm = req.body.searchTerm;
    let user = await user.find( { $text: { $search: searchTerm, $diacriticSensitive: true } });
    res.render('search', {user} );
  } catch (error) {
    res.satus(500).send({message: error.message || "Error Occured" });
  } 
}
```

and in the search form try this,#

```
<form method="POST" action="/search">
            <input type="search" name="searchTerm" class="form-control" placeholder="Search..." aria-label="Search">
        </form>
```

try like this ,